# OpenCV Recognize Roman Number from any angle

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed Python and OpenCV 2.7 x86 and using PyCharm as my IDE. Here is my request. I would like to recognize any roman number from 1 to 5 at any angle and shape. So the roman number could be thin, thick, small or big. The background of the given random number will be luckily only in one color (bright brown). Do you have any good tutorials which I could take a look at? This is what I've got so far, but it does not work correctly.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('rz-template.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('rz-image.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.3
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: rz-image.jpg][image: rz-template.jpg]

Comment: Please post a few images, and some example where your code fails, and why

Comment: @Miki Take a look at the image. I mean this is just an example. The left char will be recognized, but the right one not.